# cypress unable to assert new window url

Tags: cypress

i am at website `https://www.qatestpage.com/page1`
after click the 'testlink'

new window `https://google.com` is opened.

and I want to assert the new window url is correct.

this is my codes:

```
  cy.get('a[href*="testlink"]').eq(0).click()
   cy.location().should((loc) => {
    expect(loc.href).to.include('https://google.com')
  })
```

error:

```
Timed out retrying: expected 'https://www.qatestpage.com/page1' to include 'https://google.com'
```

Answer (score 0):

Cypress doesn't support multiple tabs feature. So when you are saying `cy.location()`, this always returns you the window where you clicked on `testlink`. So that is the reason it is giving you this `https://www.qatestpage.com/page1` instead of `https://google.com`

Please refer here `https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/trade-offs.html#Multiple-tabs`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
cy.url().then(str1 => {
    expect(str1).to.include(str2)
})
```

where str1 will capture the current url of the window and str2 is the string you want to check if it’s present in str1.